# Increasing algorithm number width in ToC coming from appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms

I want to increase algorithm number width coming from appendix.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\numberwithin{algorithm}{chapter}

%\RequirePackage{tocloft}
%\addtolength{\cftalgnumwidth}{1em}

\NewCommandCopy{\oldlistofalgorithms}{\listofalgorithms}
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{%
    \begingroup
    \NewCommandCopy{\oldnumberline}{\numberline}
    \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{Algorithm~\oldnumberline{##1:}}%
    \oldlistofalgorithms
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

    \listofalgorithms

    \chapter{Test}

    \begin{algorithm}[!htb]
        \caption{RANSAC}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \STATE Text
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    \appendix
    
    \chapter{Other}

    \setcounter{algorithm}{95}

    \begin{algorithm}[!htb]
        \caption{RANSAC}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \STATE Text
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm}[!htb]
        \caption{RANSAC}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \STATE Text
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm}[!htb]
        \caption{RANSAC}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \STATE Text
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries in the List of Algorithms (LoA) are set via `\l@algorithm`, which is created at the invocation of `\listofalgorithms` (using the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float)'s `\listof{algorithm}{List of Algorithms}`). Since this creation is only done when you're creating the LoA, you can use the new LaTeX3 hooks to insert an update to `\l@algorithm` entries just after it's created. To see where exactly, here's the (formatted) output of `\ShowCommand{\listof}` (also viewable inside [`float.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.dtx)):

```
\newcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
    \@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
    \float@listhead{#2}%
    \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
      \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
    \endgroup}}
```

Note how `\l@#1` (`\l@algorithm` in your case) is created via `\@namedef{<csname>}{<stuff>}` just before `\float@list` is called. So, we can add a hook to be executed just once at the next call to `\float@listhead` in this way:

```
\AddToHookNext{cmd/float@listhead/before}{%
  \@namedef{l@algorithm}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}}% Update spacing of \numberline's width
```

The default `2.3em` width has been adjust to `3em`. Putting this all together in your code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\numberwithin{algorithm}{chapter}

\NewCommandCopy{\oldlistofalgorithms}{\listofalgorithms}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listofalgorithms}{%
    \begingroup
    \NewCommandCopy{\oldnumberline}{\numberline}%
    \AddToHookNext{cmd/float@listhead/before}{%
      \@namedef{l@algorithm}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}}% Update spacing of \numberline's width
    \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{Algorithm~\oldnumberline{##1:}}%
    \oldlistofalgorithms
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Test}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{RANSAC}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE Text
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\appendix
    
\chapter{Other}

\setcounter{algorithm}{95}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{RANSAC}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE Text
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{RANSAC}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE Text
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{RANSAC}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE Text
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If you want the algorithms to be flush with the left margin, change the second argument of `\@dottedtocline` to `0pt`:

[image]

```
\AddToHookNext{cmd/float@listhead/before}{%
  \@namedef{l@algorithm}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{3em}}}% Update spacing of \numberline's width
```

If you wish to have this adjust *only* for the appendix area, insert the change at the point where you appendix starts:

[image]

```
...
\appendix
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\l@algorithm}{\protect\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}}
\makeatother
...
```

Comment: Is it possible to increase mentioned space just for appendix algorithms? As like my expected output.

Comment: @BahmanMirzakhani: See the end of the update answer.